# DataGridView - Save changes by using TableAdapter

Tags: c#, winforms, datatable, datagridview

There is many ways, and as a beginner to this I am very confused by `TableadApter` and `BindingSources` and so on.

What I want is simply by clicking on a button all changes made in `DataGridView` will replace the data in the `DataTable` (this DataGridView mainly is for showing and deleting data, it's like a user list and administrator can delete a user by clicking on unbound button column "Delete").

Datagridview is created with a toolbox, and bound to the DataTable (it displays almost the same data, with only some edits in WinForms).

This is all the code I have:

```
public int Business { get; set; }

public Paskyra_sarasas()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Paskyra_sarasas_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'businessDataSet.Users' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    this.usersTableAdapter.Fill(this.businessDataSet.Users); // gets the userdata and places it to DGV
    this.usersBindingSource.Filter = "[Business_ID] = " + Business; // filters the DGV by business ID (it shows the users that is registered to that specific business)
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // save changes to datatable button
{
    // Is there like a simple way to replace the data to the datatable?
}

private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Delete")
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this row?", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
            usersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    }
}
```

So is there like a simple way to save the changed data?

Comment: [Update data by using a TableAdapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2015/data-tools/update-data-by-using-a-tableadapter?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235)

Comment: Somehow it saves in the form, however whenever I try to check the data in the datatable the row I deleted is still there.

Comment: I've tried adding this.usersTableAdapter.Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true; it still doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you created your DataTable "User" in Design Mode, then in Solution Explorer, look for the DataSet's *.xsd (Dataset Design mode) and open it.  Find the DataTable / DataTableAdapter view for your Users datatable.  Right-click the usersTableAdapter and "add a query".  I assume you already have a "Fill()" query present in the tableAdapter's design mode.  Make sure not to change it accidentally.

Add 3 queries: UpdateQuery(), DeleteQuery() and InsertQuery() - be sure to enter the appropriate SQL Server command parameters for each.

Once these commands are built for your "Users" datatable/tableadapter, then you can use the usersTableAdapter.Update(dataset.datatable) method in your C# button_click() event to update any and all changes to the datatable.

When usersTableAdapter.Update(dataset.datatable) executes, it looks at the RowState of each DataRow object in the Users DataTable.

If the DataRow.RowState property contains "Unchanged", the datarow was not changed and the MSSQL table row is not updated.

If the DataRow.RowState == "Added", the InsertQuery() sql command is used to Insert the DataRow into the database table.

If the DataRow.RowState == "Modified", the UpdateQuery() sql command is used to Update the database table.

If the DataRow.RowState == "Deleted", the DeleteQuery() sql command is executed.

If you don't have the InsertQuery(), UpdateQuery() and DeleteQuery() defined in your usersTableAdapter - then the usersTableAdapter.Update(dataset.datatable) method will fail because there are no CRUD "queries" to execute.

If you create your datatable/datatableAdapter in design mode by dragging the MS SQL table from SQL Server Explorer to a new DataSet.xsd, you will be asked if you want to create SQL commands, etc.   Be sure to check the Radial buttons for "Delete", "Insert" and "Update" as well.  Then, "configure" and edit each query by adding the necessary parameters to  each sql command in the DataTableAdapter in Design Mode.

If your database is MS Access (OleDb) and not MSSQL, then the coded Update() method would look like "usersTableAdapter.Adapter.Update(dataset, datatable)".